# Add ErrorTemplate to a MahApp control without overwriting its default style

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, mvvm, mahapps.metro

I am using MahApps and working on implementing validation for TextBoxes. MahApps provides some nice properties in TextBoxes, as `Controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark` and `Controls:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton`. I am writing an ErrorTemplate using my style but I overwrite the default template of the TextBox and lose those Metro properties. How can I achieve my goal without losing the template:

```
    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{DynamicResource ErrorToolTipTemplate}" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should define your new style [based on existing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.basedon%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to keep everything it has. I guess in case of MahApps it will be `MetroTextBox`:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroTextBox}">
    <!-- your properties go here -->
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [BasedOn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.basedon) is the key to success. However, it's likely, that you're using *MahApps* controls not in just one place. Therefore, try to make your style more generic and avoid direct references to *MetroTextBox* resource in the *BasedOn*.

The more good looking XAML style would be like that:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
    <!-- your properties go here -->
</Style>
```